# Which SPDX license is equivalent to 'All Rights Reserved'?

Tags: licensing

I've got a `package.json` that's expecting a SPDX-approved license acronym, but I can't find one that means 'proprietary commercial license, all rights reserved'.

Is there one for non-FOSS, where I want to specify that I want to allow *no* reuse?

Comment: There are some problems with your question, as it is currently written.  1.  All copyrights are *always* reserved.  2.  "Proprietary commercial" is a characteristic of many licenses.  3.  There might not actually be an acronym for what you are requesting.

Comment: @RobertHarvey 1. Many software systems (eg, npm) require a license to be set explicitly. 2 and 3. Yes, the answer handles that 3.

Comment: Since this is closed I can't give another answer. But according to [1] you should set `license: "UNLICENSED",`.

[1] https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8918

Comment: `might not actually [have] an acronym for what you are requesting` is still a perfectly valid answer to a perfectly valid question.

Comment: The equivalent for **composer.json** is `"license": "proprietary"` according to [the docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#license).

Answer (score 169, accepted):

As of npm 3.10 you have to use [UNLICENSED](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#license):

```json
{ "license": "UNLICENSED"}
```

or

```json
{ "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <filename>"}
```

The value of license must either one of the options above or the identifier for the license from [this list of SPDX licenses](https://spdx.org/licenses/). Any other value is not valid.

**The following is no longer valid for current versions of npm**

For npm versions before 3.10 you may use:

```json
{ "license" : "LicenseRef-LICENSE" }
```

Then include a `LICENSE` file at the top level of the package. It could be as short as:

```
(c) Copyright 2015 person or company, all rights reserved.
```

But you might want to be more explicit about what is not allowed.

Comment: "all rights reserved", in that context, means EXACTLY what it says.  NO permissions have been given.  It is a legal term of art.  Think of it as a magickal incantation that must be uttered in precisely that form to invoke the Law Demons.

Comment: Seems the npm docs have been updated. Now suggests using: `{ "license" : "SEE LICENSE IN <filename>" }`

Comment: Edit: Ignore last comment. "SEE LICENSE IN <filename>" doesn't work when doing `npm init`. `LicenseRef-LICENSE` works

Comment: npm recommends to set `{ "license": "UNLICENSED"}` "if you do not wish to grant others the right to use a private or unpublished package under any terms". That's an even easier option than an explicit license file.

Comment: setting the license to UNLICENSED still triggers `license should be a valid SPDX license expression` for me

Comment: @cdmckay it didn't work for me too. But then I understood that my Node.js version was extremely outdated. Updating to v4.2.1 and npm to 2.14.7 solved the problem.

Comment: `"license": "UNLICENSED"` worked for me with `npm@3.8.5`

Comment: The latest update for using custom license files is as follows: `{ "license" : "SEE LICENSE IN <filename>" }`

Comment: You can also just set `"private": true` and it won't bother you about including a license.

Comment: Also make sure not to confuse the `npm`-recommended "UNLICENSED" with the SPDX compliant identifier ["Unlicense"](https://spdx.org/licenses/Unlicense.html), which is the exact opposite of "all rights reserved".

Comment: There was a typo where there was a space before `" SEE..."` and so on making this not work.

Comment: answer needs updating. Would vote down if I could.

Comment: @KevinBuchs Please elaborate and I will update the answer.

Comment: The irony is that `SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE` is notably *less clear and less searchable* than `LicenceRef-LICENSE`. I'm sure there were good reasons to not allow `LicenseRef-`, but this alone is enough to make me doubt that those reasons were good *enough*.

Comment: I would not use `UNLICENSED` - it can easily be confused with [The Unlicense](https://spdx.org/licenses/Unlicense.html) which does exactly the opposite of what you want.

Answer (score 17):

This does not exactly answer your question, but what about:

```json
{
  "license": "Proprietary",
  "private": true,
}
```

Comment: This answer reads more like a comment.

Comment: This answer also does what is needed: stops npm complaining about licenses, so it is a good one in my book.

Comment: Using "Proprietary" as the license type is not a supported SPDX type and will generate an error unless you also specify "private": true. That in turn prevents you from using NPM as a distribution channel for your proprietary package. So choose the answer above by @craig

Comment: To me, the following DOES answer the question and gives a full example of how to do it. I suggest, @WooYek, updating your answer. 

`    {
        "name": "my-descriptive-name",
        "description": "yeah, what it says",
        "repository": "npm/npm",
        "license": "Copyright Your Company 2019, all rights reserved.",
        "private": true,
        "dependencies": {
            "request": "^2.88.0",
            "request-promise-native": "^1.0.5"
        }
    }`

Comment: For brevity I did not want to put the usual copyright stuff. Just the bare minimum required for a packaged to be treated as proprietary software.

Answer (score 3):

Not so sure about specifically npm, but SPDX standard [version 1.2](https://spdx.dev/wp-content/uploads/sites/31/2023/09/spdx-1_2.pdf) (2013) and later has provision for specifying arbitrary custom licensing terms, in their *machine-readable* [license expressions](https://spdx.dev/ids#how) format. Section `Other Licensing Information Detected`:

> ```
> 5.1.4 Data Format: "LicenseRef-"[idString]
> where
>   [idString] is a unique string containing letters, numbers, “.”, “-” or “+”.
> ```

This is also present in the latest (today) spec [version 2.3](https://spdx.github.io/spdx-spec/v2.3/other-licensing-information-detected/) (2022).

So basically, we should be able to say:

- `{"license": "LicenseRef-Proprietary"}`,
- `{"license": "LicenseRef-Custom-Commercial-Agreement"}`,
- `{"license": "LicenseRef-PrivateUndisclosed"}`,

and so on, along those lines.

---

Relatedly, there's also the special keyword `NOASSERTION` — but it isn't considered a "valid SPDX License Expression", and I'm not positive if it's intended for package developers. See [PackageLicenseDeclared](https://spdx.github.io/spdx-spec/v2.3/package-information/#715-declared-license-field): that keyword is apparently for license-scanning software to express *"I failed to determine the SPDX ID of the package's license, or didn't even try"*.